# Can I do NASM file processing in online NASM compilers?

Tags: assembly, nasm, jdoodle

I am new to NASM and only at the basic level but is it possible to create to or open files from the computer hard drive through online NASM compilers? I am using JDoodle and Rextester NASM compilers but neither of them seem to be working.

Comment: You should not be using online tools for development.  Program on your computer instead.  And to answer your question: likely not.

Comment: You're going to need a debugger for asm development; unless those online dev envs let you single-step and watch registers change when running your program, you're wasting your time.  Take the time to set up a dev env locally, in a VM if necessary.